# Find Spectrum - Harmonic Oscillator with Ladder Proportional Potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

I'm asked to find the spectrum and the ground state (in the number basis) of the following Hamiltonian:

$$H = \hbar \omega a^{\dagger}a + Ja + J^{*}a^{\dagger}$$

I tried to solve the equation $H|\Psi\rangle = E|\Psi\rangle$ where I used some general wave function $|\Psi\rangle=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n|n\rangle$ but the equations I got where too complicated to solve. I guess there is some easy way to solve it without too much algebra but I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write this in terms of $x$ and $p$, you will see that you have a harmonic oscillator shifted in $x$ and/or $p$. Thus, try defining 
$$
b^\dagger= a^\dagger + \alpha, \quad b= a+\alpha^*
$$ 
with $\alpha$ a constant to be fixed so that $\hbar \omega b^\dagger b$ reproduces your original Hamiltonian.  You should also be able to verify that $b^\dagger$ and $b$ have the correct commutation relations for a harmonic operator.